# Confused by using too many for loops, if and else statements

Tags: python, qgis

I am developing a plugin for the GIS software, QGIS. I created a `QTableWidget` and wish to extract values from it:

[image]

Problem is, I use a lot of `for` loops and `if` `else` statements which, up until the last few lines, seems to work fine. I can't seem to follow the logic now as the line `print constraint_name` only prints off the last value "Example_2". I could take it out of its corresponding `else` statement and then it will print all values correctly but I need to set it inside a condition:

```
qTable = self.dockwidget.tableWidget  # QTableWidget
example_group = root.findGroup('Main group')  # Group containing sub groups
all_items = []
gis_map = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "Map" )[0]  # Layer map in QGIS
idx = gis_map.fieldNameIndex("Rank")  # Get "Rank" attribute field from gis_map
for row in range(qTable.rowCount()):
    for col in [0]:  # For first column "Constraint name"
        constraint_item = qTable.item(row, col)                            
        constraint_name = str(constraint_item.text())
    for col in [1]:  # For second column "Rank"
        item = qTable.item(row, col)
        item_string = str(item.text())
        all_items.append(item_string)
        for group in example_group.children():  # Search for specific group
            if group.name() == "Sub group":
                if len(set(all_items)) == 1:  # If all items are the same
                    # If "Rank" field exists in layer map
                    if idx == -1:
                        print 'success'
                    else: 
                        print 'fail'                        
                else:
                    if idx == -1:
                        print constraint_name
                    else:
                        print 'fail'
```

Is there a way to tidy this up and still get the correct results?

Comment: `for col in [0]:`?? Something seems fishy there

Comment: both of your 2nd level `for` loops are useless.  `for col in [0]` and `for col in [1]` can be refactored to nothing, since they each execute exactly once with a known value.

Comment: Also it seems that your innermost `if` statements can be reversed, since you print `fail` if `idx == -1` regardless of the value of `len(set(all_items))`

Comment: @RNar - I'm not sure but isn't that the first column of the `QTableWidget`? Because I can print off the values from that by adding `print constraint_name` in the same loop.

Comment: @Joseph as Ian said, all that for loop is doing is assigning `col = 0`, which means the for loop itself is useless

Comment: @RNar - Ahh I see now, thanks! That makes sense. I will try and make the necessary edits in response to all the comments =)

Comment: A way to avoid this in the future is to not use lines like `for col in [0]:  # For first column "Constraint name"`
The comment there hints that you should define a variable named `constraint_column` or something and then use it in the `for` statement.

Comment: @JeremyWeirich - That's a good tip, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sincere thanks to the commenters who directed me to a much more efficient solution, here is the working code which works (I'm sure it can be refined further):

```
qTable = self.dockwidget.tableWidget
example_group = root.findGroup('Main group')
all_items = []
gis_map = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "Map" )[0]
idx = gis_map.fieldNameIndex("Rank")
for row in range(qTable.rowCount()):
    constraint_item = qTable.item(row, 0)                            
    constraint_name = str(constraint_item.text())
    item = qTable.item(row, 1)
    item_string = str(item.text())
    all_items.append(item_string)
    for group in example_group.children():
        if group.name() == "Sub group":
            if idx == -1:
                if len(set(all_items)) == 1:
                    print 'success'
                else: 
                    print 'fail'                        
            else:
                print constraint_name
```